# How to use precompiled headers in Qt project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, precompiled-headers

My IDE: Visual Studio 2010, I use Qt add-in for VS, Qt ver. 4.8.1

I have faced with the **problem** while trying **to create precompiled header(pch)** in my Qt project.

*My usuall approach for creating pch in non Qt project is:*

1. Create header;
2. Include files which will be precompiled in header;
3. For every source file in the project state in it`s properties if it will use pch;
4. For one source file in project state creation of pch;
5. Include pch in all source files.

As **those action failed** for Qt project I decided what it happens due to pch should be included to all files generated by MOC.

I read the article in QtAssistant on precompiled headers and did the following:

1. Created header file;
2. For all .cpp files in project set option use pch and for one create
3. Converted to qmake generated project
4. I ran qmake -project
5. I modified generated .pro file, here it is:

   TEMPLATE = app
   TARGET =
   DEPENDPATH += . GeneratedFiles
   INCLUDEPATH += .
   PRECOMPILED_HEADER = StdAfx.h
   QT += network

   ## Input

   HEADERS += server.h StdAfx.h
   FORMS += server.ui
   SOURCES += main.cpp server.cpp StdAfx.h.cpp
   RESOURCES += server.qrc
6. I ran qmake
7. open .pro file and tried to build it and got the error:

   Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'StdAfx.h': No such file or directory

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a StdAfx.h file and inside of it include all the headers that you want to be precompiled?

Comment: Yes of course! I have mentioned that I created .h file, but didn`t stated that it is StdAfx.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.
The only thing needed to be done in order to use precompiled header in project is to **include
the following statements in .pro file:**

```
CONFIG += nameOfPrecompiledHeader.h
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = nameOfPrecompiledHeader.h
win32-msvc* {
PRECOMPILED_SOURCE = nameOfFileInWhichCreateOptionWillBeSet.cpp /* other .cpp files will be with use option*/
}
```

after .pro modification and running qmake all .cpp files will be set up for usage of pch and one for it`s creation(nameOfFileInWhichCreateOptionWillBeSet) and .pch will be generated

Comment: I would like to add a warning here that following this advice [may lead to problems](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44071). The key point I think is that QMake will automatically generate your pre-compiled source file for you for Visual Studio and so you do not have to create one yourself as you would using vanilla VS.

Comment: This is not working on Qt 5.5.0 (OSX). Using CONFIG += precompile_header as @Gordon Freeman indicates makes it work.

Comment: @Borzh please compare the date of the answer and the date when Qt 5 has been made available. My answer is for Qt 4.8

Comment: I am just indicating that your solution is not working with current version of Qt, so other users don't spend time trying.

Answer (score 16):

Create your precompiled header file and include the desired headers.

pch.hpp:

```
// precompiled headers

// add C includes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
// add C++ includes here

#include <iostream>
#include <QtGui>

#endif // __cplusplus
```

Then in your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += precompile_header
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = pch.hpp
HEADERS += pch.hpp
```

Qmake will now automatically set the correct options for the compiler.

Comment: Does your answer contains any new information which wasn`t covered in my question or my answer? What is the purpose of your answer? Whom are you addressing it?

Comment: @spin_eight Your own answer gives the wrong syntax for adding the precompiled header to the .pro file. The `CONFIG` option should be `precompile_header` not the name of the header file itself. Also the `PRECOMPILED_SOURCE` option is not documented anywhere. My answer is correct as far as the docs go (and it's always worked fine for me).

Comment: @spin_eight You are wrong. Rather than repeat myself I'll just link you to [the relevant documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-precompiledheaders.html) which does exactly what I've shown.

Comment: CONFIG += precompile_header makes it work on Qt 5.5.0 (OSX)

Comment: Note: `PRECOMPILED_SOURCE` is essentially an undocumented build artifact for `PRECOMPILED_HEADER`. The use of `PRECOMPILED_SOURCE` (with different values) is necessary *if* you are going to use the same `PRECOMPILED_HEADER` from multiple projects and they may build in parallel. Otherwise, each build will rewrite the header.h.cpp file, and other builds may try to process it while it's in an indeterminate state. This needs to be considered a per-target temporary temporary file, but it isn't handled that way by qmake by default.

Comment: I would just like to add, that for some reason qmake always triggers compilation of precompiled headers with both g++ and gcc (on Windows with MingW), which obviously barfs out a pile of errors, so do not forget to guard your C++ precompiled header with `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: @GordonFreeman documentation says "You do not need to include the precompiled header file in HEADERS, as qmake will do this if the configuration supports PCH". I'm just not sure what the "configuration" means, perhaps it means the compiler.